# Batch file not working

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, windows-server-2012

I am trying to run some commands in batch file on windows server 2012 but it's not working properly. What i am doing here. Get all files(.docx) from current directory in loop, convert file into pdf and move into other folder.

```
cls
@ECHO ON

for  %%i in (*.docx) do  
    soffice  /-Y --headless --convert-to pdf %%i
    MOVE /-y C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\results\*.pdf   "C:\xxx\xxx\xx-xx\results\pdf"
```

Can anyone help me about this what i am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: Is that your actual code? Where are the parentheses for the FOR block?

Comment: oh i missed it.. is this problem only ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to do this...

```
cls
@ECHO ON
for  %%i in (*.docx) do soffice /-Y --headless --convert-to pdf %%i
MOVE /-y C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\results\*.pdf "C:\xxx\xxx\xx-xx\results\pdf"
```

Comment: can i execute this file through php?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php